# Combining Composite and Template Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I have three devices which have different `Run()` implementations and interfaces. These devices may contain other subsystem or may contain other devices.

I know that I should use [Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern. but in template pattern I need to inherit device1 device2 and device3 from device class. On the other hand, in Composite pattern I have device, CompositeDevice and subsystem classes.

I am quite confused about combining these two patterns. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you please post your initial thoughts or your initial design/solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take Composite Pattern from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern. Both Leaf and Composite inherits from Component class. And now, to combine tamplate pattern with composite pattern all your devices should inherit Component class - these are your Leaf classes. Finally Composite class can use your leaf classes.

```
     Component   ----------
  ^   ^   ^    ^           |
  |   |   |    |           |
Dev1 Dev2 Dev3 Composite<>-|
```

Component class is interface containing Run() function declaration.

Comment: in this design, can devices have composite device in it? i mean i want to design dev1 which have dev4 in it. is it possible?